# unit test @Async in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have a method that returns a future of custom object as shown below

```
@Async
public Future<Map<ObjectId, Field>> execute(final List<GlobalValidation> globalUniqueValidations,
        final Map<ObjectId, ValidationField> evalFieldValueMap, final Map<ObjectId, Field> inputFieldValuesMap) {

    LOGGER.debug("Triggering unique validations");

    if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(globalUniqueValidations)) {
        return new AsyncResult<Map<ObjectId, Field>>(inputFieldValuesMap);
    }

    for (final GlobalValidation globalValidation : globalUniqueValidations) {
        executeUniqueValidationPerCollection(globalValidation, evalFieldValueMap, inputFieldValuesMap);
    }

    return new AsyncResult<Map<ObjectId, Field>>(inputFieldValuesMap);
}
```

please help me understand on how to write unit test case to return `AsyncResult<Map<ObjectId, Field>>` object type using MockitoJUnitRunner

Comment: Your method is not asynchronous, so you can unit test it like any other method. Also show what you have done so far and where you are blocked if you want help.